# I got 'duplicate section' errors when compiling boost_regex with size optimization (-Os)

Tags: boost, mingw, compiler-optimization

compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev6.7z

boost: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/boost_1_52_0.7z

(both on D: drive)

boost_regex compiled with:

```
b2 --prefix=D:\boost toolset=gcc --with-regex --layout=tagged release
```

code:

```
#include <boost\regex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::regex reg("[a-z]+");
}
```

compiled with parameters:

```
g++ -I "d:\boost" -Os -o test.exe test.cpp -static -L d:\boost\stage\lib -lboost_regex-mt
```

error:

```
d:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mt.a(regex.o): duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEE[__ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEE]' has different size
d:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mt.a(regex.o): duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE[__ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE]' has different size
d:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mt.a(regex.o): duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTSN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE[__ZTSN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEEEE]' has different size
d:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mt.a(regex.o): duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTSN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE[__ZTSN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseE]' has different size
d:\boost\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mt.a(regex.o): duplicate section `.rdata$_ZTSN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEE[__ZTSN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorISt13runtime_errorEE]' has different size
```

It compiles ok, but I haven't yet tested if it will be working in more complex code. Removing the `-Os` switch clears the error but app size is 2x bigger then.

Maybe I should build Boost with size optimization too also but I don't know where to pass this option in b2 command line.

Comment: [This unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635485/regex-boost-library-linking-in-release-mode-warns-duplicate-section-has-differe) has the same problem. One of the comments suggests that the problem may be isolated to mingw-w64. Mingw-build's g++ 4.8.0 also presents this problem and fedora 17's g++ 4.7.2 does not, so he/she may be right.

Comment: As you said using size optimization (adding `optimization=space` to your boost build command) seems to remove the problem. You should put that as an answer if you can confirm that it works. PS: Well, the problem is now reversed, the compiler spews those errors/warnings whenever you don't use `-Os`.

Comment: @llonesmiz : thanks! this works. The problem was that I could not find this option, it is not printed by `b2 --help` nor `--help-options`.

Comment: If you plan to use only g++ (or compilers that accept the same command line flags) you could also use `cxxflags=-Os`. There is also `linkflags` to pass options to the linker.

Comment: I have the same problem with Crypto++. Both with MinGW and MinGW-w64.

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2042/ and https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/345/

Comment: @Nikolai "-march=i686" worked for crypto++ with mingw.

Answer (score 15):

In my case boost 1.58 was internally compiling with "-march=i686", but my code wasn't. Adding "-march=i686" to my project got rid of all "duplicate section".

lesson learned: always make painstakingly sure that all libraries and the main project are compiled with identical compiler options.

Comment: Same for me. Between boost 1.57 and 1.58 this must have changed silently. Took me some time to find it.

Comment: "-march=i686" worked for crypto++ with mingw. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a compiler bug. The workaround in my case was to add `-fno-tree-vectorize`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I compile my code use gcc-4.9.1 in MinGW32 with a lib which use gcc-4.4.7 as the compiler. And I also used ccache to speed up,ccache is also a problem. Remove the cache in ~/.ccache/ and recompiled then I workaround this.